# System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer order of property deserialization

Tags: c#, wpf

my model have a series of setters and getters.  Some setters call methods that are dependent on other properties.  This works fine because when contructing the object in code, i control the order in which properties are set.  However during serialization/deserialization, i am running into an issue where a setter that also invokes a method that is dependent on another propert (say property1) is run before property1 is actually been set.

Is there a way to control the order of property setters being called when deserializing using `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`?

```
 public class MyClass
{
    public String[] Property1 { get; set; }

    private String[] _property2;
    public string[] Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set { _property2 = value; UpdateSomething(); UpdateSomething(); RaisePropertyChanged("Property2"); }
    }

    public void UpdateSomething()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Property1.Length == Property2.Length); <!--When deserializing, need Property1 set before property2 to avoid issues
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: its a tough one to avoid in this case..the only way to avoid this that i can see is not to use serialization or creating a custom deseerializer (which i want to avoid).  in this case, when a property changes i want to do something.  if i use the getter or setter, to do that something, the race condition exists still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i went with was to create a scaled down persistable model with only the fields i want to persist or restore.  The real model has an overloaded constructor that takes the persistable model and can restore itself from it..thereby allowing me more control over how properties are initialized/set.